# Javascript code not extracted with python code

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to extract .mp4 link from a website, which is shown only in "Inspect Element" tab in web browsers.

I read on the internet that i need to use selenium and for example PhantomJS to get that code. I tried it but i get HTML file which is visible in "Show source code"

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Nevendary\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs')
driver.get("https://filmovitica.com/pucanj-u-sljiviku-preko-reke-1978-domaci-film-gledaj-online/")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

print(driver.page_source)
```

I expect to get code that includes: https://fs40.gounlimited.to/tea5u5akd32qzxfffpqyfndb6resauu5w43w7enoxkvu6sjtrf5hfhbz3ika/v.mp4"

but I get just normal HTML of the website

Comment: Is that for the main clip that you can play on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching the page source you can directly get the `src` attribute of the video element, which contains the link you are after.

The video link is in an `iframe`. getting the page source without switching to the frame would not return the video link.

I've used chromedriver for the example.

**Try This:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://filmovitica.com/pucanj-u-sljiviku-preko-reke-1978-domaci-film-gledaj-online/")

vframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@width='900']")

driver.switch_to.frame(vframe)

videoElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#vplayer > div > div.container > video")))

print(videoElement.get_attribute('src'))

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `PhantomJS` try use `ChromeDriver` with `headless` options.This gives me the output you are after.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path of chrome driver',options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://filmovitica.com/pucanj-u-sljiviku-preko-reke-1978-domaci-film-gledaj-online/")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Note: You can download chromedriver from following link if you don't have chromedriver installed based on your browser compatibility.Please read release notes before downloading any chrome driver for compatibility. [Download Chrome driver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Another way to do it using Beautiful Soup which is python library.

```
 import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    data=requests.get('https://filmovitica.com/pucanj-u-sljiviku-preko-reke-1978-domaci-film-gledaj-online/')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

Note : It is easy to install `pip install beautifulsoup4` You can check following link about Beautiful Soup [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the html it does indeed seem that link is generated inside the same url that the iframe uses. You can use requests to get that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://filmovitica.com/pucanj-u-sljiviku-preko-reke-1978-domaci-film-gledaj-online/')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('iframe[allowfullscreen]')['src'])
```

You can locate how it is (your string) generated in one of the script tags within the uri (see line highlighted at start in blue:

[image]

Later in that js:

[image]